# Target Unreachable, identifier 'demoBean' resolved to null

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I am developing a web application using JSF on Netbeans 7.0. I have created 2 pages: one for entering persons name and other to display that name. I am using a java bean with get and set methods.

I get an error when I submit my form on first page the code.

This is my first page `index.xhtml` to accept name:

```
<h:form>
    Enter your Name : <h:inputText value="#{demoBean.name}" required="true"/>
    <br/> <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="welcome.xhtml"/>    
</h:form>
```

This is the other page `welcome.xhtml` to display the name:

```
<h:body>
    Hello #{demoBean.name}
</h:body>
```

This is the managed bean `demoBean.java`:

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean; 
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped; 

@ManagedBean()
@SessionScoped

public class demoBean {
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

This is the error which I got when I submit the fist page:

> /index.xhtml @10,86 value="#{demoBean.name}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'demoBean'
>       resolved to null

Comment: pls add your faces-config.xml

Comment: @Kushan how do i do it.?

Comment: opps, you must be define your beans on faces-config.xml, otherwise you can use bean annotaions

Comment: i used.@ManagedBean() and @SessionScoped annotations .do i need to add anything more.?

Comment: pls add your full jsf page and bean codings

Comment: <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
     <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/welcome.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list> is this the way...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7162/discussion-between-prakash-d22-and-kushan)

Comment: put your controller class code and just check you created demoBeanclass object in load method..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The JSP framework expects your bean class name to conform to the Java naming conventions, i.e. be "CamelCased" (e.g. `DemoBean`), in which case it will assume the bean will be referenced in the JSP by the default name formed by converting the first character of the bean name to lower case (`demoBean`).

As you have deviated from the framework's expectations, you need to indicate the name by which you refer to your bean in the JSPs, either by specifying it in the `@ManagedBean` annotation or in the optional faces-config.xml file.

Comment: i cant find faces-config file.. where to find it..

Comment: i was using ManagedBean which was using default class name then i used ManagedBean(name="mybean") and it worked thanks @James McLeod and why -1.?

Comment: Because this isn't a solution. If you don't specify the name, JSF will default to the classname with 1st character lowercased. OP's concrete problem is that he ignored Java Naming Conventions and the way how tutorial/example code is written.

Comment: I have updated my answer (hopefully improved it) to address BalusC's comment, the contents of which I was previously unaware of.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue. I added an extra annotation. 
{ @Named("demobean") }

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to check is to make sure you have all of the required jars in your path(or use maven:) ). I started getting this issue in Glassfish with all of my beans properly set because I changed the directory that stores my Primefaces3.5 jar.